# Changing the format of numbering definition?

Tags: numbering, theorems

I want to appear statement "Def 1.1.1-" instead of "Def 1.1.1." I use Texlive 2017 and the following codes:

```
 \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    %\usepackage{hyperref}
    \makeatletter
    \def\@thm#1#2#3{%
        \ifhmode\unskip\unskip\par\fi
        \normalfont
        \trivlist
        \let\thmheadnl\relax
        \let\thm@swap\@gobble
        \thm@notefont{\fontseries\mddefault\upshape}%
        \thm@headpunct{-}
        \thm@headsep 5\p@ plus\p@ minus\p@\relax
        \thm@space@setup
        #1% style overrides
        \@topsep \thm@preskip              
        \@topsepadd \thm@postskip      
        \def\@tempa{#2}\ifx\@empty\@tempa
        \def\@tempa{\@oparg{\@begintheorem{#3}{}}[]}%
        \else
        \refstepcounter{#2}%
        \def\@tempa{\@oparg{\@begintheorem{#3}{\csname the#2\endcsname}}[]}%
        \fi
        \@tempa
    }
    \makeatother
    \theoremstyle{definition}
    \newtheorem{definition}{ِDef}[section]
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{TEST}
    \section{Introduction}
    \begin{definition}
        content...
    \end{definition}
    \end{document}
```

But when I use hyperref package, output is "Def 1.1.1." Can you help me?

Comment: The trailing `-` looks awkward, in my point of view

Comment: Since you're loading the `amsthm` package, would you want to create a solution that makes use of this package's machinery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest to use a special theorem style rather than explicitly changing `\@thm` which is the base macro for all theorems definitions, meaning any theorem will have the same settings unless explicitly changed with `\theoremstyle` later on.

Change the spacings at will, the given `3pt` values are just the usual values from the `amsthm` manual.

I find the trailing `-` at the end of the theorem number weird, however, but this is my opinion only.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheoremstyle{dashed}{3pt}{3pt}{\fontseries\mddefault\upshape}{}{\bfseries\itshape}{-}{3pt}{}

\theoremstyle{dashed}
\newtheorem{definition}{ِDef}[section]

\begin{document}
\chapter{TEST}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{definition}
    content...
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution for users of the `ntheorem` package.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % optional
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % optional

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremseparator{-} 
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{definition}{ِDef}[section]
\crefname{definition}{definition}{definitions}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just for this example
\setcounter{section}{1}

\begin{definition} \label{def:dash}
    content...
\end{definition}
A cross-reference to \cref{def:dash}.
\end{document}
```